# Let $a>1$, and let $r$ and $s$ be any rational numbers. Show that $r<s \iff a^r<a^s$

Tags: analysis, exponentiation, rational-numbers

I'm currently trying to prove the following:

Let $a>1$, and let  $r$ and $s$ be any rational numbers.  Show that $$r<s \iff a^r<a^s$$

I have just started taking to Introduction to Analysis and I find it very much difficult to prove such a thing. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: What techniques do you have?  If you know about $e^x$ and the associated natural logarithm then you can write $a^r=e^{r\log a}$ and so on.  Otherwise you could note that $a^r< a^s \iff 1<a^{s-r}\iff 0<s-r$.

Comment: $a^x$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$ for $a>1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take the logaritms of both members: $$\log_a(a^r)<\log_a(a^s)$$ and because $a>1$ you have that it is true if and only if $r<s$.